# How to change theme in android programatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-search

i'm using actionbarsherlock for Actionbar, here by default a theme will be set. Upon expansion of searchview i need to change the theme of my actionbar, i'm doing like below

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setTheme(R.style.CalendarTheme);
    return true;
}
```

New theme is not getting reflected, same theme i'm using in other activities in Manifest file, it works well. How to change theme dynamically in android?

Comment: That is no possible. You can set the theme with `setTheme()` in `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView()`, but there is no way to change it again afterwards.

Comment: without restarting the activity/application

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an Activity's theme after any Views have been instantiated.

From the [`setTheme(int)` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme(int)):

> Note that this should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before calling `setContentView(View)` or `inflate(int, ViewGroup))`.

You could manually change the styling of your Views, but you cannot change the theme.

Comment: Oh, in my case upnavigation icon will be just 3 bars, which indicate its a sliding menu. But when my search expands, i need arrow to be replaced by that. How to do any idea?

Comment: For a quick workaround, you could restart the activity after changing the theme:

protected void restartActivity()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}